# Can't load library in C#

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to use NDesk.Options library in my code. I have the file NDesk.Options.dll on my computer. I compile my program using

```
dmcs -R:/path-to-dll/NDesk.Options.dll Program.cs
```

The program compiles fine showing no errors. However when I run the binary using mono I get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NDesk.Options, Version=0.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'NDesk.Options, Version=0.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NDesk.Options, Version=0.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'NDesk.Options, Version=0.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

The library has no dependencies and the path to dll is correct.

Here is the pkf-config file for the library I have on my computer.

```
prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
exec_prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
assemblies_dir=${libdir}/ndesk-options
Libraries=${assemblies_dir}/NDesk.Options.dll
Sources=${assemblies_dir}/Options.cs

Name: NDesk.Options
Description: C# Program Option Parsing Library.
Version: 0.2.1
Requires: 
Libs: -r:NDesk.Options.dll
```

Comment: *The library has no dependencies and the path to dll is correct.* - I don't know, my hunch is that one of those two assertions is wrong.

Comment: If the path is wrong the program does not compile. I tried doing that. And the webpage for NDesk.Options mentions no dependencies.

Comment: The fact that it mentions no dependencies does not mean that there are none. I'm just saying that, after debugging this issue numerous times, it almost always a missing dependency (missing dll is an easy fix).  That's also what the error message is telling you.  What about assembly versions?  Is the version of the assembly you have the same as the one in the error message?

Comment: Why is your `PublicKeyToken` null? And what is NDesk.Options' token value? Generally, the C# compiler wants your DLL versions to match if you have the token specified in your configuration file...

Comment: I don't know about the 'PublicKeyToken'. Is there something else I need to do to load the library?